# Поведения try...catch при выделении памяти

Tags: c++

Я правильно понял, что если я запишу:

```
try {
   char * str = new char[30];
   throw "exception";
   delete [] str;
} catch(...) {
   //здесь ничего не будем делать
}
```

то произойдет утечка памяти? А если запишу без delete, то утечки памяти не будет?

Также меня интересует, что если исключения произойдет по условию, то как быть с удалением, или же память удалит С++ сам?

Если я не буду возбуждать исключения, то НЕ будет утечки? Например:

```
try {
    char * str = new char[30];
    //кое-что делаем, но исключения не возбуждаем.
    delete [] str;
} catch(...) {
    //ничего не делам
}
```

И в каких случаях память нужно удалять память в catch?

Comment: В первом примере утечка будет в любом случае, а во втором не будет (но исключение может произойти, если new выкинет bad_alloc)

Comment: используйте умные указатели или просто RAII и не будет подобных проблем.

Comment: @Waylander123, тоесть не нужно удалять память в try...catch?

Comment: @KoVadim, сначала нужно понять принцип работы основы

Comment: в с и с++ принцип простой - **создал - удаляй за собой**. Никто просто так не будет удалять. То есть, удалять нужно. Другое дело где и когда. Но раз Вы пишете на С++, тогда и пишите на с++, а не на с+. В данном случае я бы просто объявил на стеке и все само подчистилось. Либо просто  объявил `vector<char>` или что уже мелочиться - `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *str = nullptr;
try {
   str = new char[30];
   throw "exception";
   delete [] str;
} catch(...) {
   delete [] str;
}
```

По Стандарту, применение оператора delete к указателю на уже очищенную память игнорируется. В C++ блока finally нет, потому можно сделать так. Или обернуть строку умным указателем, который в деструкторе автоматически дернет delete.

ЗЫ Но вообще, советуют правильно, если это С++, то нужно по возможности пользоваться классами стандартной библиотеки в общем и std::string в частности.

Comment: для примера выделил память через char.

Comment: @Free_ze, наверное Вы, говоря

     применение оператора delete к указателю на уже очищенную память игнорируется

все же имели в виду **нулевой указатель** (т.е. переменную, значение которой NULL), а вовсе **не память, которую уже один раз освободили**?

--

А в этом конкретном примере, почему Вы не написали просто один `delete[]` *после* всего блока `try {...} catch(){...}` ?

Comment: @avp
Да, насчет указателя вы правильно уточнили, т.к. в случае другого указателя на ту же память было бы бы UB. Пункт 3.7.4.2.4 Стандарта:

> Если аргумент, переданный деаллоцирующей функции стандартной библиотеки является указателем, то это ненулевой указатель. Деаллоцирующая функция должна освободить память, на которую ссылается указателем, что побьет все указатели, ссылающиеся на любые части освобожденной памяти. Последствия использования битого указателя (**включая передачу их деаллоцирующей функции**) не определены.

Comment: @avp
 Вы также правы по поводу одного delete, безусловно, но я написал в ответе именно такой избыточный в данном контексте вариант, указывая на отсутствие finally-блока, который будет полезен в случае необходимости выхода (любым способом) из функции в catch.

Comment: Именно по этой причине (плохая совместимость с исключениями) в современном C++ не пользуются нативными указателями. Пользуйтесь `shared_ptr`, и всё будет автоматически правильно.

Comment: [Пять подводных камней при использовании shared_ptr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191018/).

Все это напоминает известную поговорку -- хвост вытащил - нос увяз.

Общего решения, конечно, нет. 

Просто в своих проектах надо всегда помнить о KISS принципе, бритве Оккама и т.п.